# Bind to click-event to dynamically created button without selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to dynamically create elements using javascript and jQuery. Currently I'm stuck with binding a simple click-event to a dynamically created button-element.

The button is created with

```
var theButton = $("<button>...</button>");
```

Now I want to bind the click-event, so I added

```
theButton.on("click", function(){...}); // which is not working
```

Other solutions pointed out, that it must be bound to a container. So I ended up with

```
$(document).on("click", theButton, function(){...}); // this fires no matter where I click
```

The problem is the selector (2nd param of the `on` method) which is a jQuery-object at this point.

Also tried

```
theButton[0].onclick = () => alert("Clicked")
```

which is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It's working

```
$(function(){
   var theButton = $("<button>button</button>");
   theButton.click(function(){
      alert('clicked');
   })
   $('body').append(theButton);
})
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uprm34o/)